# CSS transform rotate pause choppy

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to pause a spinning transformation. However, the animation is very choppy; it does not pick up where it left off. I am pausing animation by toggling a class:

```
.pause { 
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Please see the attached code snippet. The pause class is toggled when you click the document. Notice the jerking of the arrows. I want the animation to resume where it left off.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e){
   Array.prototype.forEach.call(
      document.querySelectorAll('#container>div'),
 function(d){
            d.classList.toggle('pause');
 });                               
});
```

```css
#container { 
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    margin-left:50px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid black;  
    overflow: visible;
    
}

#container>div {
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Green_Arrow_Right.svg/600px-Green_Arrow_Right.svg.png);
    background-size: 100%;
}

#d1 { height:200px; width:200px; top: 0; left:0; animation-duration: 20s; }
#d2 { height:80px; width:80px; top: 0; right: 0; animation-duration: 20s; }
#d3 { height:60px; width:60px; bottom: 0; left: 0; animation-duration: 20s; }
#d4 { height:200px; width:200px; bottom:0; right:0; animation-duration: 20s; }
#d5 { height:100px; width:100px; top: 160px; left: 300px; animation-duration: 20s; }

.cw {
    animation-name: rotate; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear; 
}

.ccw {
    animation-name: rotateccw; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;  
}

.pause { 
    animation-play-state: paused;
}



@keyframes rotate {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes rotateccw {
    from {transform: rotate(360deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(0deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="d1" class="cw"></div>
    <div id="d2" class="ccw"></div>
    <div id="d3" class="cw"></div>
    <div id="d4" class="ccw"></div>
    <div id="d5" class="cw"></div>
</div>
```

Update: This issue only shows up when I use Chrome 45.0.2454.101 m for Windows. Firefox 41.0.1 and IE 11 both work as expected.

Update: Chrome 46.0.2490.71 m was released. Issue persists.

Comment: Using chrome mobile (android) - smooth as silk

Comment: Buttery-smooth here: Chrome 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit) on Max OS 10.10.5.

Comment: The first pause is smooth(ish). All others after that get jerky. I am on Chrome 45.0.2454.101 m (Win). I will test it with a few more browsers.

Comment: it appears that the longer you leave the animation running, the larger the change when you pause/resume it.

Comment: in your JS, instead of selecting the elements inside the click listener function do it outside, it should be more performant

Comment: seems to be a Blink issue - Opera has the same problem. You could file a bug report on that.